# How do I create custom sections in my app.config?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I'd like to add a custom section to my app.config. In that section, I'd like to add rows with three pieces of data. Then, I'd like to read my app.config (the custom section) and build a collection of items.

Can I create a customer section? If so, how do I create the section and how do I read items in it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

MSDN covers very throughly everything that you need on this topic. See [How to: Create Custom Configuration Sections Using ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx), [System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx) and the links therein.

Answer (score 0):

You would create a custom section group and a handler to deal with that section group.  The process is outlined the associated in MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You'd create a descendant of [ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx). Microsoft's documentation contains an example of how to use it to make custom app.config sections.

Answer (score 0):

The CodeProject article [Unraveling the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx) is probably the best piece I've seen on the hoops you need to jump through to build a custom config section.

There's also, the [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com)'s [Last Configuration Section Handler I'll Ever Need](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/the-last-configuration-section-handler.html) and [The Last Configuration Section Handler...Revisited](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/the-last-configuration-section-handler-revisited.html), which avoid the problem by creating a generic XMLSerializationHandler: all you need to do is provide an class that is XML serializable. Easy!